# Is the code "while(condition);" valid and what does it mean?

Tags: c, while-loop

Can we put semicolon like `while(condition);` in a C Programming?
If `while(condition);` is valid, what does it mean?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, as I found out after a few wasted hours in my first programming class.

Comment: Condition is irrelevant, all of them evaluate to either true or false.  Granted, things can be done inside the condition as discussed below, but this question appears to be mostly about syntax and/or behavior as related to the loop.

Comment: Yes, it's valid.  How else would you write a do-while loop?

Answer (score 56):

```
while (condition);
```

is the same as

```
while (condition) 
{
}
```

It can be used for waiting loops, e.g.:

```
while (!isLightGreen()); // waits until isLightGreen() returns true
go();
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will result in execution continually looping and checking the condition, so the process/thread does not actually wait but use CPU time all the time.

Comment: @GCATNM: right, but sometimes (e.g. controller applications waiting for a signal) there is really nothing else to do than just wait. If this is not the desired behavior the loop body should allow thread/task switching (e.g. using sleep) or use another mechanism for waiting (e.g. call-back-functions, interrupts); but this was not the question...

Comment: @Brian and also busy-wait :)

Comment: Put some kind of sleep so you don't kill CPU

Comment: @GCATMN - you are assuming that the isLightGreen() function doesn't block.

Comment: @Peter M: The name of the function hints that it is non-blocking.

Comment: **Condition** may also include **action** as well, it's an arbitrary expression evaluation after all. So that this **whole** discussion is ridiculous IMHO. All the bla-bla bout processor loads, spin-locking, blocking, shmocking, etc.

Comment: I agree with @valdo, though I would put it differently. In this example it is hard to tell what kind of loop this is, since we don't know anything about isLightGreen().

Comment: @Brian - Such a hint is still an assumption.  You are assuming that just because in the past you saw a similar name matches such a pattern, that this different name matches the same pattern.  Yet the associated comment suggests that it is a blocking function.  So whose assumption is correct?

Comment: The comment is true whether the condition blocks or not. If it blocks, the name is poorly chosen, and the loop is unnecessary. If it does not block, the example is poorly chosen -- its most frequent usage by beginners is as an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 27):

It means the body of the loop is empty. Typically this pattern is used when the condition itself does some work.

For example, this loop can copy bytes within the condition:

```
while ( '\0' != (*pt++ = *ps++))
            ;
```

If you're using a semicolon, it's a good idea to put it on a separate line so that it looks less like a mistake. I personally tend to use empty braces -- {}, and sometimes a comment that the empty block is intentional.

**Edit:**

In the second comment, Tom Anderson notes an improvement over a lone semicolon. [Google's C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Loops_and_Switch_Statements) recommends either this or {}.

```
while ( '\0' != (*pt++ = *ps++))
            continue;
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation that it's useful when the loop condition has a side effect. -100000 for putting the semicolon on a separate line! Horrible! FWIW, there is a good crossposted flamewar going on on comp.lang.java.programmer/comp.lang.c about how to style this construct which may be of interest.

Comment: `while (condition) continue;` (with a line break before the continue and/or braces, as you prefer) has been suggested as a readable and reasonably uncontrived form.

Comment: As I mentioned, I use braces rather than a semicolon. K&R did use the semicolon, on a separate line. The "continue" pattern seems an improvement. I don't consider flamewars on the small stuff to be valuable.

Comment: Can we have another flame war over the reversed condition?  I strongly prefer '`while ((*pt++ = *ps++) != '\0')`, but that's the beauty of flame wars.  (FWIW: I prefer the semi-colon on its own on the next line.)

Comment: I was thinking of adding a similar example, but perhaps with different style. Style aside, this is a good example of a common use of an empty "while" body.

Answer (score 10):

Because the condition may actually have side effects, such a construct is allowed. Consider the following:

```
while (*p && *p++ != ' ');
```

This would advance the `p` pointer to the first character that is a space.

You may even use the comma operator to have ordinary statements inside the condition:

```
while (do_something(), do_something_else(), i < n);
```

Because statements connected with the comma operator evaluate to the rightmost statement, in that case `i < n`, the above is identical to:

```
do {
  do_something();
  do_something_else();
} while (i < n);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can.  It just means that the while loop will keep looping until `condition` is false.  For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int x = 10;
int func()
{
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return --x;
}

int main()
{
  while(func());
  return 0;
}
```

But generally people don't do this, as it would make more sense to put the logic in the body of the loop.

Edit:

There are some examples of this in use, for example, copying a null-terminated string:

```
char dest[256];
char *src = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
while(*(dest++) = *(src++));
```

Comment: While this may be an example of an empty body loop it is also an example of poorly designed code (hence a little less useful IMHO).

Comment: @Lee-Man - exactly, I even point out that it's not a good idea, the logic belongs in the body of the loop.  My second example is a little better, if only because it's a somewhat common pattern and most C programmers would recognize it instantly.

Answer (score 5):

It will keep evaluating condition until it's false. It is a loop without a body.

Programmers often add a space before the semicolon, i.e.

```
while(condition) ;
```

or empty braces:

```
while(condition) {}
```

to show the empty body is intentional and not just a typo. If you are reading some existing source code and wondering why there is an empty loop there you should read the next few lines as well to see if the semicolon should really be there or not (i.e. do the next few lines look like the body of a loop or not?).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's correct. It will loop the condition until it's false.

```
while ( condition() );
```

Answer (score 4):

I always write this as:

```
while (condition())
    continue;
```

So that it's obvious that it wasn't a mistake.  As others have said, it only makes sense when condition() has side effects.

Comment: condition without side-effects also makes sense if it checks volatile variable, when it just waits for asynchronous event.

Answer (score 3):

while() is a loop. You're probably looking to do a "do-while" loop. Do-while loops run in this format:

```
do
{
    // Your process
    // When something goes wrong or you wish to terminate the loop, set condition to 0 or false
} while(condition);
```

The one you have listed above, however, is an empty loop.

while() loops work nearly the same; there is simply no "do" portion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It means that **keep checking condition** until it evaluate to **false**

Answer (score 3):

The key to understanding this is that the syntax of the *while loop* in "C" is as follows:

```
while (condition) statement
```

Where *statement* can be any valid "C" statement. Following are all valid "C" *statements*:

```
{ statements } // a block statement that can group other statements

statement; // a single statement terminated by a ;

; // a null statement terminated by a ;
```

So, by the rules of the *while loop*, the *statement* part (null statement in your example) will execute (do nothing) as long as *condition* is *true*. This is useful because it amounts to a busy wait till the *condition* turns *false*. Not a good way to wait, but useful nevertheless. You could use this construct, for example, if you want to wait for another thread (or a signal handler) to set a variable to some value before proceeding forward.

Answer (score 3):

The code `while(condition);` is perfectly valid code, though its uses are few. I presume `condition` is a variable, not a function — others here discuss functional `condition`.

One use of `while(condition);` may be to block while waiting for a [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) e.g. [`SIGHUP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP), where the signal handler changes the variable `condition`. However, this is usually not the best way to wait for a signal. One would typically use a `sleep` in the loop i.e. `while(condition) { sleep(1); }`.

The absence of any [`sleep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28operating_system%29) means that the loop will be continually processing in the interim, and likely wasting processing cycles. Unless the process has its resources managed (and even there...), I think this is only suitable where the loop needs to be broken in an interval less than the granularity of the available `sleep` command (i.e. sleep is granulated by the second, but you need the code after the look executed with sub-second response time). That being said, a blocking pipe or socket may be preferable to signals, performance wise – though I don't have any emperical data to back that up offhand, and I suspect performance may vary significantly depending on the platform.

One *could* have `condition` modified by a parallel thread of the same process, but I'd think one should prefer to do that by way of a mutex or semaphore (i.e. `condition` may need to be more than a simple variable).

I hope that's helpful, or at least food for thought!

Answer (score 2):

It is just an empty loop. It would help if you explained what the condition is.

Answer (score 1):

If the evaluation of the condition does not modify a value that influences the condition itself, `while(condition);` is an empty infinite loop, meaning it will never terminate (and never do anything except consuming CPU time).

Comment: Unless you're waiting on something from another thread or a register to change (or something similar). i think you've over-generalized it.

Comment: This is true in a single threaded program, but the value of condition could be changed by other threads.

Comment: If condition is false it won't loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

it is absolutely correct. it means doing nothing in the loop,just polling the condition.And it is common in embedded system`s codes.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a while loop with no execution body

```
while(condition);
```

is same as

```
while(condition)
{
    }
```

Comment: We have a coding standard at work that always requires us to use braces even for simple if/while/for statements.  This may be a good reason why; the second statement is so much clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Just another usage not described here:

```
do
{
   if(out_of_memory)
     break;

   if(file_does_not_exist)
     break;

   return ok;

} while(0);

return error;
```

This allows you to avoid several return calls or goto statements.

Comment: I consider this an anti-pattern.  For heavens sake, just use return, or even goto where it's the better construct.  Don't write code with goto's masquerading as structured.